# how to write Get() pointcut to retrive the attributes that have been used in the program in AspectJ

Tags: get, set, aspectj, pointcut

I have written the following pointcut but it is giving the run time error (Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError)

**pointcut traceAttribs():(get(* *));**

Comment: Without some more information on how that pointcut is used, what your code looks like etc., you won't get any answers. A StackOverflowError isn't very likely to come from a pointcut like that, so your problem might be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that you need to create an aspect that knows your methods argument in real time.

There is a useful simple examples in [Mkyong's page](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/) and probably your need is on point 8.

If you want to get a method name and arguments in your aspect you could write something like this:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

   @Around("execution(* com.your.package.YourClass.yourMethodAround(..))")
   public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("Your method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("and method arguments: " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

    System.out.println("Your method will be executed. ");
    joinPoint.proceed(); //continue on the intercepted method
    System.out.println("Ended execution");

   }
}
```

Hope to help